# Prevent Quartz job recovery from starting on long-runnng tasks

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm building Quartz jobs with the RequestRecovery flag set, because I have multiple server instances running and if one fails while running a job, I'd like another instance to pick up that job and restart it.

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SystemMaintenance>()
                .WithIdentity("SystemMaintenance", "SystemMaintenance")
               .RequestRecovery(true)                   
               .WithDescription("System task that runs every 6 hours")
               .Build();
```

However, what I've noticed is that if the job is running for a very long time (say over 10 minutes), the other instances will start running the job because they assume that it has failed, even though it is running fine.

Is there any way that I can periodically ping Quartz, perhaps through JobExecutionContext, to let it know that a specific instance is still running and processing a job, to prevent others from assuming failure and starting it?

**EDIT:**

My configuration looks like this:

```
        NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "Scheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";

        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = ConnectionStringService.DatabaseConnectionString;
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
```

Comment: I don't know why Quartz would fire the job again just because it is running a long time? According to the doc (http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html), it should only be re-executed if the scheduler has a "hard shutdown". How are you storing job state so that your other server instances know about the scheduler that is running the "SystemMaintenance" job?

Comment: @ChrisKnight, my job store is SQL Server and I execute jobs on an array of Azure Worker roles.  I configure quartz as so:
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO"; properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";  plus the regular config options for the db etc.

Comment: Potentially a quick fix for having the job not be fired again while it is already running is to place the "DisallowConcurrentExecution" attribute on the job. See http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html